# How To Setup A Sms Sending Website in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, bulksms

i have a project on newsletter management system. in asp.net.. i am student and i want to provide such a facility in my project for who is become a member of my website and join a group in that so .. whenever admin put a news or any tips and trick.. it will be sent on 
that group member .. via sms..

so.. can any one tell me how can i setup sms feature website?

i am allready know about email feature.. but i want to add sms feature in it..

help is required .. do know anything about sms sending feature in .net enter code here

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351765/how-to-create-an-sms-gateway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576940/how-do-i-design-sms-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeep Mobile is free:

http://www.zeepmobile.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use Skype API. It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

Most cell phone carriers have a email to SMS feature.

If someone has an AT&T account and a number of 202-555-1212, you can send an email to `2125551212@Txt.ATT.Net` and AT&T will convert it to an SMS message and send it to a their telephone.

So when a new user creates a profile, you will have to capture their phone number and  their carrier as well.

Alternatively, if you do want purely SMS messages, there are several services like the one shown below that will send out SMS messages for you.

http://www.hummingbytes.com/SolutionPages/Solutions_SMS.aspx

Comment: i want to developed it.. so tell me how can i develop website.. it is not a mobile website..

Answer (score 0):

you can use any API of sms providers like way2sms..

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?
   uid=*****&pwd=****&msg=" + textBox2.Text + "&phone=" + textBox1.Text + "&provider=way2sms");             
HttpWebResponse myrep = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```